# Do marine predators hunt or fish?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

As an example, which is correct: "The seal hunted the fish" or "The seal fished the fish"?

What about marine birds, do they hunt or fish?

Comment: They can catch and eat fish.

Comment: @mahmudkoya - I don't think so.  I don't think the catching and the eating are discrete actions.  I think it's more combined.

Answer (score 8):

The relevant meaning of "Fish" is [attempt to catch fish [M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fish).  That's technically applicable, but doesn't quite capture the survival nature of the process for the predator.  There are also aquatic animals other than fish that get eaten.

The relevant definition for "hunt" is [to pursue for food](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hunt).  It isn't limited to doing it on land.

All of the documentaries I've ever seen that touch on the subject refer to aquatic animals "hunting".  However, they usually refer to what marine birds do as "fishing".  For that matter, when bears catch fish, they also call it "fishing".

It isn't clear what the basis originally was for selecting which term to use.  Just speculation: "hunt" seems to be used when the activity is in the predator's own natural environment, while "fish" is used when a non-aquatic animal does it.  That would make sense since the only way the predator can pursue it's prey is if they're both in the same environment.  Otherwise, it's more of an opportunistic endeavor.

Comment: I think the reference to usage on documentaries is perhaps the best one is able to do here; I'd agree with your claim. With perhaps an odd quirky exception when it comes to the angler fish.

Comment: In my head, _fishing_ involves being outside the water and moving yourself or some kind of aid into the water in order to catch fish in their trajectory moving through the water. The hunter is essentially stationary (more or less) in the water, intercepting fish that pass by. Humans and birds do that, and even bears that fish with their paws… but aquatic animals that swim around in the water and carry out the fish-hunting process entirely within the water don’t. They chase and catch the fish by moving through the water like the fish themselves.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, and yet when humans put on diving gear, swim underwater in pursuit of fish for food, and catch them with a spear gun, we still call that fishing. So I suspect there's more to the terminology convention that we're not catching. Unless maybe it's just the fact that underwater is not humans' natural environment. :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I can honestly say I’ve never seen or heard of anyone doing that, so that hadn’t influenced my mental image of what ‘fishing’ is in the slightest. ;-)